# Cycles image sequences not working (blender 3.6.7)

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing

I forgot to add my project file in the last post sorry

PJ https://drive.google.com/file/d/1cKIk8dACivDxo-Is8FgdlMNddb64E1AW/view?usp=sharing

So I have this animation rendered as image sequence and in eevee the animation works fine but when I switch to cycles it just completely blank
EEVEE:
[image]

CYCLES:
[image]

thanks

Comment: Hello, hard to tell, maybe share your file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is your *Texture Coordinate* has the *From Instancer* option enabled, which can only work if your display object was instanced on another object from which it should inherit the coordinates. But it is not, so it does not show the texture correctly. This does not happen in *EEVEE* because this functionality only works in *Cycles* and is ignored by *EEVEE*.

[image: from instancer]

Comment: omg thankssssss

Comment: @lamdi You're welcome. Maybe you would consider accepting the answer if it helped?